# How to Generate Shopify Abandoned Cart "key" Parameter? (Email Hash?)

Tags: hash, shopify, shopping-cart, checkout, email

I’m looking at abandoned checkouts ion Shopify and hoping to create my own links. I see the Checkout object has a token to construct a URL like this:

`shop.com/{{ checkout.id }}/checkouts/{{ token }}`

That’s great. However, looking in Shopify admin I can see the links sent to customers also have a `key` URL parameter that seems to be some kind of email hash, since when you click on the full link, you are taken to the Checkout in a *logged-in state*… Since I have the Customer emails, does any one know how to create that hash?

Answer (score 0):

The answer my friend, is blowing in the wind...

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/abandoned_checkouts

You can clearly see how to deal with that hash right there!

Comment: Dave! {{ token }}?key={{ hash }} ... how do I generate the hash? That docs page does not seem to have info on that

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Why not just use the URL from Shopify? Why do you have to make your own?

    "abandoned_checkout_url": 
    "https://www.snowdevil.ca/orders/14168/68778783ad298f1c80c3bafcddeea? 
   recovered=1"
The recovery URL that's sent to a customer so they can recover their checkout.

Comment: That's not in the Checkout object on the client side : )
    `{
      "apiHost": "shop.myshopify.com",
      "geolocatedAddress": { },
      "i18n": { },
      "locale": "en",
      "page": "show",
      "requiresShipping": true,
      "step": "shipping_method",
      "token": "abc123",
      "AddressFormat": { }
    }`

Comment: You are free to send me your problem via an email, and I will do my best to spell out a working solution Rick!